# Disabling autorotation in ios 10 not working for specific view

Tags: ios

I'm trying to disable autorotation for a particular view (the first view the user sees) in an ipad app, in the view's .m file i've used the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    // Return a bitmask of supported orientations. If you need more,
    // use bitwise or (see the commented return).
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    // return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    // Return the orientation you'd prefer - this is what it launches to. The
    // user can still rotate. You don't have to implement this method, in which
    // case it launches in the current orientation
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

This doesn't however seem to work as the view still rotates to landscape (see screenshot)

[image]

Strangely the above code does disable autorotation for 2 other .xib views. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

As an aside, would this have anything to do with the fact that this is the fist view presented by the app, i.e.:

[image]

I've now tried to override the navigation controller method using the below but still no luck, the view still rotates!!! - any ideas?

```
@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end

@implementation CustomNavigationController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    // return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    // Return a bitmask of supported orientations. If you need more,
    // use bitwise or (see the commented return).
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    // return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    // Return the orientation you'd prefer - this is what it launches to. The
    // user can still rotate. You don't have to implement this method, in which
    // case it launches in the current orientation
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

@end
```

Comment: you need to override your navigation controller's methods, because the system manages the orientaion support based on what the navigation controller says – in your case at least; and the default implementaion of the navigation controller does not care about individual view controller's custom orientaion support.

Comment: Awesome, makes sense, how would i go about overriding the navigation controller methods?

Comment: maybe, you could create a subset of the navigation controller and override the related methods.

Comment: ok, really not asking for the code for this but I dont know where to start to create this subset, is there anywhere I can look to learn how to do this?

Comment: From what I can tell I'm unable to override the navigation controller methods, is there another approach I can take?

Comment: well... if you are not familiar with OOP, I would suggest to learn that first; but you are not unable to override it, you are already creating subsets of the `UIViewController` class in your project, I presume; so, you just need to do the same thing with a different base-class – in this case, the `UINavigationController` class.

Comment: I've tried to override the UINavigationController class as outlined in the edited question - still no joy!

Comment: so, what is the problem then? how did you instatiate _your custom_ navigation controller? I see no notes about that in your post; you may want to explain that as well, because if it turns out that you don't actually use it, it would be silly to expect it working...

Comment: Ok does holex, leave it with me, I'll figure it out from here